# Flask OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error when creating zip of a folder and sending as a response

Tags: python, flask

I have an endpoint in flask application which downloads a folder by creating zip of it and sending it in the response. Here is the code for it

```
def download_data(zip_file_name):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    shutil.make_archive(zip_file_name + current_time, 'zip', folder_path)

    @after_this_request
    def cleanup(response):
        try:
            os.remove(zip_file_name + current_time + ".zip")
            return response
        except Exception as ex:
            LOG.error(f"Error while removing the zipped dataset after downloading {ex}")

    return send_file(zip_file_name + current_time + ".zip")
```

Surprisingly the response of the api is sent and has a 200 status code. But in the logs it shows below error

```
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

data = self.file.read(self.buffer_size)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 365, in __next__

Traceback (most recent call last):

Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
```

NOTE - This download is from OBS buckets and I am able to download/send individual files in the response.